# Async/Await vs Parellel.For, which is better in this instance?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

So I have 1000s of items to check whether they are up to date.  Each one of those items requires reading thousands of files (some of which might be the same file across different items).

Currently this is implements using the TPL (async/await), one for each file it has to read and one for each item it has to check.  This works fine, except for when I profile it, about the 3rd most expensive function is TrySteal in the thread pool.

Using the visual studio concurrency viewer, I see that 99% of a threads time in spent in concurrently related items, and only 1% in execution.  It is this that leads me to think that I am perhaps just creating too many tasks (note: I don't use Task.Run anywhere, just await).

Would Parellel.For be any less overhead than reading a bunch of files using async/await?  How much overhead is expected using the task programming library?

Comment: Have you checked Resource Monitor (available through the Performance tab on Windows Task Manager) to see if you are hitting the performance capability of your disk subsystem? If so, you may need to rethink the problem. Caching data, using multiple drives, using an appropriate RAID set, SSD(s), ... .

Comment: Probably neither.  Instead you may want to consider _TPL DataFlow_ as you can limit the messages in each block in a way suitable for the number of I/O operations as a time

Comment: I have four hardware raided SSDs, and since 90% of the files are in memory already, the disk barely ticks up at all.  However, cpu usage is at 100% with all programs running at the same time, so I am trying to optimize by reducing the cpu usage.  It appeared that the task scheduler was a big part of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking files on the hard drive, I don't think that this task is very well parallelable. If you are trying to read thousands of files at the same time, you just make the process much slower, because it cannot read that many of them at the same time, and even worse, it cannot cache too many into memory.
The fastest option, without optimization of the checking process itself, should be just running it consecutively.
If you really want to optimize it, I suggest to loop through the files, checking for each item, instead of looping through item, checking each file. In this case, it might be effective even to do it in multiple threads (not all at once though).

Update:
For the case when you have enough memory to cache all your files, then it does not restrict multithreading that much. Still, I would suggest to limit amount of parallel threads to number, comparable to amount of processor cores you going to work with. It is better to do it with Parallel.ForEach(). Also, Parallel.Foreach() clearly states, that you loop is async, so the code will be easier to understand.

Comment: In this case, most of the files fit in the memory (and they are fairly likely to already be in memory).  Does the same advice apply even if the files are in memory?  By in memory, I mean they are probably in the standby list as they have just been used by a process before it.

Comment: @user2460953 No, my advice does not apply then. I updated my answer.

Comment: Since I have multiple items that may wish to read in the same files, I assume I should be just doing a lock inside the parallel for loop on an object that represents the file right?  That way if two items want to hash the same file, one wins and the other sees it is already hashed after the lock resolves.

Comment: @user2460953 It is hard to tell if it is effective optimization in your case or not. But if you are doing the same task for each file, why don't you just make a full list of files and then process them (in one or multiple threads) - it may significally simplify logic and let you easier to optimize processes.